# When to go from basic .erb to Sinatra or Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

In the old, pre-Ruby & Rails days o' the web, one typically used PHP when they needed to add server-side functionality that HTML or CSS could not provide. Nowadays, we have a ton of options for creating super-dynamic websites and applications. I recently discovered that you can just use **.erb** files on a web server to get the same functionality as throwing PHP files in there in order to make things more dynamic.

I am building my first from-the-ground-up website, which will actually be my own personal website. I'm a huge **Ruby** nerd, and definitely want to invest in the technologies I'm most learned and familiar with. I want to build with a focus on *simplicity*, *speed*, *and power* in mind. I love **Rails**, and have had the most training in it, so I am, for the time being (for version 1.0 of my beloved sexy website), **excluding Sinatra or other frameworks** from my list of choices.

Now, here's the question, which is admittedly a bit ambiguous: **when is it appropriate to go from using regular old .erb files to using a full-blown Rails framework**? The website won't be processing any users or anything, and will mostly be a portfolio for my art, music, and technology works. I'll be doing a blog with **Jekyll**, additionally, so that level of dynamic content will be handled separately.

Comment: On a side note, any thoughts on other great-server side dynamic content with Ruby? I totally love AngularJS, but that's Javascript and is client-side.

Comment: You could save yourself some time and money and just go pure Jekyll. I run my portfolio/blog/everything else off Jekyll hosted on S3 for a couple bucks a month. I would say go Rails when you need a database otherwise stick to something simpler. Unless of course it's just for fun and practice, but then *that* would be the criteria for when to go to Rails and you wouldn't be asking.

Comment: Can I see your Jekyll blog? I'm looking for something fairly robust, but I don't know how far Jekyll delivers, and I don't know if what I'm looking for would require Rails.

Comment: http://www.alexmarchant.com

Comment: DAAAAAANG! That's sexy. That looks like what I need. Care to add it as an answer so I can accredit you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strait ERB files are great to set up a simple template system. Jekyll is a more robust way to build a simple static site using templates. It's great for a personal site that doesn't have dynamic content, it doesn't work when you have users storing new content constantly to a database, which then needs to be rendered on the fly to a new page. Rails is based on the idea that you need a database, if you don't need it skip Rails and save yourself loading time, hosting costs, and sysadmin headaches.

Also check out https://github.com/laurilehmijoki/jekyll-s3 you can host your site on S3 for dirt cheap.